# Rspec Capybara Selenium tests fail but not the same tests in Rack::Test

Tags: ajax, selenium, rspec, capybara

I have a whole bunch of tests set up in Rspec/Capybara using Selenium (without transactional fixtures) to test Ajax functionality. In general, I've found Selenium to be unreliable and not deterministic as laid out [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22098031/why-might-i-be-getting-intermittent-test-failures-using-selenium-for-javascript) although I still don't entirely know why.

However, now I've just started writing a new set of tests for a calendar page which also uses Ajax. I've only written two tests so far:

```
  describe "view calendar page" do
    before { visit show_calendar_path }

    it { should have_content today.strftime('%B %Y') }
    it { should have_selector "td##{today.to_date}" }

  end
```

Where:

```
  let(:today) { Date.today }
```

These are two tests that are entirely independent of any Ajax functionality (both of those tests are for stuff that is there when the page loads). The second test is simply to test that the cell for the calendar for today's date is there. When I don't use `:js => true` and thus am not using Selenium, this test passes. However, as soon as I insert `:js => true` the test fails with the following error:

```
  1) view calendar and create events should have selector "td#2014-07-07"
     Failure/Error: it { should have_selector "td##{today.to_date}" }
     Selenium::WebDriver::Error::InvalidSelectorError:
       The given selector td#2014-07-07 is either invalid or does not result in a WebElement. The following error occurred:
       InvalidSelectorError: An invalid or illegal selector was specified
     # [remote server] file:///var/folders/60/bynswzcx6p3bx0bdr61xbtf00000gn/T/webdriver-profile20140707-57439-11dc64c/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/driver_component.js:9444:in `FirefoxDriver.annotateInvalidSelectorError_'
     # [remote server] file:///var/folders/60/bynswzcx6p3bx0bdr61xbtf00000gn/T/webdriver-profile20140707-57439-11dc64c/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/driver_component.js:9502:in `FirefoxDriver.prototype.findElementsInternal_'
     # [remote server] file:///var/folders/60/bynswzcx6p3bx0bdr61xbtf00000gn/T/webdriver-profile20140707-57439-11dc64c/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/driver_component.js:9506:in `FirefoxDriver.prototype.findElements'
     # [remote server] file:///var/folders/60/bynswzcx6p3bx0bdr61xbtf00000gn/T/webdriver-profile20140707-57439-11dc64c/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command_processor.js:11455:in `DelayedCommand.prototype.executeInternal_/h'
     # [remote server] file:///var/folders/60/bynswzcx6p3bx0bdr61xbtf00000gn/T/webdriver-profile20140707-57439-11dc64c/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command_processor.js:11460:in `DelayedCommand.prototype.executeInternal_'
     # [remote server] file:///var/folders/60/bynswzcx6p3bx0bdr61xbtf00000gn/T/webdriver-profile20140707-57439-11dc64c/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command_processor.js:11402:in `DelayedCommand.prototype.execute/<'
     # ./spec/requests/calendar_pages_spec.rb:32:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

When using `save_and_open_page` this code is clearly on the page:

```
<td id="2014-07-07" class="day today">
```

Any idea why my apparently simple and straightforward test won't pass in Selenium??

**Update**

@user2709090 solved it below. It's, apparently the fact that CSS doesn't allow ID's starting with a number as a valid ID. `Rack::Test` doesn't care about this, but Selenium apparently does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=718326 - since a#2014-07-07 is a css selector and css doesnt allow ID selectors beginning with numbers it appears the error is correct - racktest is just way more lenient than a full browser -  notice an all numeric ID is actually valid in html5, its just not acceptable in CSS

Answer (score 0):

Check your value of Capybara.default_selector - if its :xpath that would give the result you're seeing since td#2014-07-07 is not a valid xpath selector.

Comment: That value isn't specified anywhere in my project that I can find. But would this only be dependent on the Selenium driver? The exact same test passes if I'm not using Selenium.

Comment: No, it shouldn't be selenium specific.  Other things to check would be that you don't have css or javascript that are hiding the elements, since neither of those are evaluated by racktest

Comment: Also -- what is the document type?  Different types have different valid ids, for instance HTML4 dom ids must begin with a letter which would make the id 2014-07-07 invalid

Comment: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=718326    -  since  a#2014-07-07 is a css selector and css doesnt allow ID selectors beginning with numbers it appears the error is correct - racktest is just way more lenient than a full browser

Comment: That's it!! Please feel free to submit this as an actual answer so I can check it off as you having answered it and you'll get the reputation points for it.